# Why aren't reference operators used in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, reference, frameworks

I've been programming for quite a while with PHP. Recently I decided to try and use a framework. I happened to pick Symfony2. One of the first thing I noticed was that I've never encountered any reference operator(`&`). I used them frequently in my previous projects.

I've found this on [php.net/manual/..](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php#93812).

> Note that in PHP5 you generally don't need the reference operator -- at all -- when dealing with class objects, because PHP5 implements objects using Instances (which are more like C pointers than PHP's references system).

Are references uncommon in frameworks, or perhaps in general in PHP5?

### Edit

I know what references do and how they work. I wonder why the Symfony2 examples on the site do not use reference operators anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact if you use passing object as argument to function, PHP won't create copy of the object but simple points to the same place in memory where this object exists. So there is no need to use reference as long as you don't want to do some complex stuff (point to another object/variable in memory).

You should look at [Object and references](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) in PHP manual.

You can also consider the following code:

```
<?php


class A {
    public $x= 20;
}


$a = new A();

echo $a->x."<br />";
change($a);
echo $a->x."<br />";

changeRef($a);

echo $a->x."<br />"; // you get notice in this line. $a is no longer A object
echo $a."<br />";



function change(A $b) {
    $b->x = 10;
    $b = 15;   
}


function changeRef(A &$b) {
    $b->x = 10;
    $b = 15;   
}
```

I've created 2 function **change** (without reference) and **changeRef** (with reference).

As you see when using change function even if we don't use reference, when using property assignment inside function also property of variable `$a` has been changed - it's because `$a` and `$b` **pointed to the same place in memory**. However if inside the same function I set any other object (in this case simple int) to variable `$b`, nothing more happened. Simple `$b` is now pointing to some other place in memory where `15` was placed but `$a` is pointing to the same place in memory as earlier.

However in send function (with reference) after assigning `$b` value `15` it means that `$a` has been also assigned the same value (**$b is reference to $a**) so after running this function when you try to display property of `$a` it's impossible no more (warning raised) because `$a` is no longer `A object` but simple int with `15` value.

I hope this clears you this issue a bit and now you understand why references don't need to be used very often when using objects.

**EDIT**

As you mentioned using references for arrays, PHP uses **copy-on-write** mechanism. So if you pass array to function or other variable as long as you don't modify it no copy will be created even if passing arrays as argument.

Consider the following code:

```
  $arr = [1,2,3];
  show($arr);

  function show($a) {
     foreach ($a as $item) {
        echo $item;
     }
  }
```

in above case no copy of `$arr` will be created so there is no need to use reference in this case. So unswerving your question if you don't have to modify the array you don't need to use reference. Probably that's why Symfony doesn't use references in that cases.

In addition references make code less clear because if you don't go to function declaration you won't know that it could modify your data. So probably that's the extra reason they are not so commonly used.

Comment: Like I said in my question, I used references a lot. I know what they do and why they are used. I wonder why they don't use the reference operator in Symfony2 example code when passing plain arrays etc.

Comment: @BennoZeeman I've added more info to my answer (look at info after Edit)

Comment: To many developers, passing arrays as a reference was considered as a bad practice because arrays are not objects and reference of arrays would decrease readability of the code. PHP5 has different interfaces that can be implemented on classes so the code can iterate through their properties (as an example, see [the documentation for Iterator interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php). Doctrine for example uses the [ArrayCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html) class instead of a array.

Answer (score 0):

[Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

> **Note**: There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass the argument by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);. And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.